# unique or semiunique module ID or Name for any Linux Kernel Module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, unique-key

Is there any way for me to query for an ID or name that could be used to identify a loaded Linux kernel module from within the module.

ex:
within sample.ko

```
int id = get_module_id(???);
printk("%d", id);
```

The goal is to use the IDs within a resource tracking system to identify what modules have failed to release resources, so the ID may be theoreticaly non-unique as long as it is unique in a practical system.

The goal here is to minimize change to individual components, so solutions like "define your own identifier" will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If each module version is sufficiently different, the size of the module might be good enough for your purpose:

```
[wally@lenovotower ~]$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
uvcvideo               51149  0 
snd_usb_audio          85970  1 
snd_usbmidi_lib        14807  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_rawmidi            16204  1 snd_usbmidi_lib
videodev               70682  1 uvcvideo
media                   9214  2 uvcvideo,videodev
vfat                    7031  0 
fat                    37971  1 vfat
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea, and might work, but how can the size of a module be easily discovered from within that module? Better yet would be to get the string used for the "Module" column, since the whole point is to log allocations for an eventual report to a user.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the module name as a key.

Alternatively, you could make use of the preprocessor and use the filename (**__*FILE*__**) as a key. While it's not guaranteed, the filename is pretty unique for every module.